# Problem in importing database to customer computer

Tags: c#

I'm exporting my database to a customer which shows me the following error:

> Could not load schema model from package. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Internal Error.  The internal target platform type Sql110DatabaseSchemaProvider does not support schema file version '2.5'.

I installed SQL Server 2012 on the customer's PC, the same version in which it is created.

I also installed Crystal Reports on the customer's computer.

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: please share the version of SqlServer running on both the systems.

Comment: Both r same same version sql server 2012 64 bit

Comment: I'm not sure, but can you please verify .net framework versions on both machines. As of error message, I think that customers .net framework `Sql110DatabaseSchemaProvider` class does not support _schema file version '2.5'_, but your (developer computer) version of .net framework does.

Comment: from where i can check this option in SQL server

Comment: Both are same i checked on both PC under the help tab in SQL server

Comment: It is not about SQL server, it is about ".net framework".

Comment: Do not export/import.  You can Deattach the database from original PC.  Make a copy mdf file and then Reattach on both local and remote PC.

Comment: I don't know this method can u please explain it more by sharing article on it or a video